# How to count the number of grouped rows in mysql when I already count the total rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, distinct

I have the below table and I want to do the following:

1. Count the number of times each item appears in the table
2. Count the `DISTINCT` number of items
3. Group the items by name

   ```
   +-------+---------+
   |  id   |  names  |
   +-------+---------+
   |   1   |  Apple  |
   |   2   |  Orange | 
   |   3   |  Grape  | 
   |   4   |  Apple  | 
   |   5   |  Apple  | 
   |   6   |  Orange | 
   |   7   |  Apple  | 
   |   8   |  Grape  |  
   +-------+---------+
   ```

   For the 1. and 3. points I have the following query which works quite well:

   ```
   SELECT * , 
      COUNT(names) as count_name, 
      FROM tbl_products WHERE type = '1' 
      GROUP BY names
   ```

   So I get:

   ```
   Apple  (4)
   Orange (2)
   Grape  (2)
   ```

Now I want to also count the number of grouped by rows and added a line to count the distinct elements, however there is some problem, since MySQL accepts the query but cannot output a result:

```
SELECT * , 
   COUNT(names) as count_name, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT names) as count_total 
   FROM tbl_products WHERE type = '1' 
   GROUP BY names
```

Can anyone advice what might be the problem?

EDIT: For more clearance I want to get a table like this:

```
    +-------+---------+------------+-------------+
    |  id   |  names  |  count_ctg | count_total |
    +-------+---------+------------+-------------+
    |   1   |  Apple  |      4     |      3      |
    |   2   |  Orange |      2     |      3      |
    |   3   |  Grape  |      2     |      3      |
    +-------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I am not sure what you expect. Could you provide an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: sure, I want to get 1. Number of times each item appears in the table, i.e. Apple - 4, Orange - 2, Grape - 2, then I want to get 2. How many distinct items exist in the table - i.e. 3 - we have Apple, Orange and Grape and finally I want to 3. group the items by name, i.e. get 3 rows.

Comment: I mean, could you edit your question to show an output of the query you'd like to have.

Comment: Edited, I am thinking now I can try to get the count of the query via PHP...it might be easier to do.

Comment: SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE JOIN A_TABLE ON B_TABLE

Comment: You already get ALL this information from the first query in your question. See my answer below.

Comment: So count_total is always going to be equal to the number or rows in your result?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the query you are using:

```
SELECT * , 
COUNT(names) as count_name, 
FROM tbl_products WHERE type = '1' 
GROUP BY names
```

This query achieves all three objectives.

1) You get a count of the number of each name value in `count_name`.

2) The number of distinct `names` values will be equal to the number of rows in the result set , since you are grouping by `names`. Pretty much any client-side MySQL DB connection library will enable you to retrieve this value.

3) You meet your third criteria of grouping by name by explictly using `GROUP BY names`

Of course the value for `id` in the result set is meaningless, you may want to only select `names` and `count_names`.

Comment: Hi Mike, my initial question was if I can get the count only via SQL in the returned result but enayway, I finally decided to leave the query as it is and then I just executed a new count via php for the query result.

Answer (score 1):

1-.Count the number of times each item appears in the table:

```
SELECT names, count(names) FROM tbl_products WHERE type = '1' group by names
```

2-. How many distinct items exist in the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT names FROM tbl_products WHERE type = '1'
```

3-. Group the items by name:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT names) as Total FROM tbl_products WHERE type = '1'
```

As your last EDIT (ALL IN ONE):

```
SELECT id, names, count(names), total FROM tbl_products, (select count(distinct names) as total from tbl_products) as total WHERE type = '1' group by names
```

Comment: @user3132858 you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of distinct names in a subquery, then OUTER JOIN that thing back into your main query where you already solved for 1 and 3:

```
SELECT names , 
    COUNT(names) as count_name, 
    Total
FROM tbl_products 
    OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(DISTINCT names) as Total FROM tbl_products) t2 
WHERE type = '1' 
GROUP BY names
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Windowing OVER()

This query returns the row_number() function as the id column in the results, and the over(...) for row_number requires an order by clause.  You could order by whatever you want, but it most be ordered by something.

```
;WITH vwGroups (name, Quantity) AS 
(
    SELECT  name
    ,       COUNT(*)
    FROM    tbl_products
    GROUP BY name 
)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Quantity DESC, name) AS id
,       name
,       Quantity AS count_name
,       COUNT(*) OVER () AS count_total
FROM    vwGroups
```